# json_decode php ajax :Invalid argument supplied foreach

Tags: php, json

Here is my sample json string `data`

```
[{"ratetype":"Y","hotelPackage":"N","roomtype":"Deluxe Double Room","roombasis":",Complimentary Wi-Fi Internet, Breakfast, ","roomTypeCode":"0000015468","ratePlanCode":"0000120709","ratebands":{"validdays":"1111111","wsKey":"fOnrQW3wP9U6eaST9cxEwNldIVM6N6LdxDrDapJ4gq4xUB8SLli5fMQ6w2qSeIKuoaZbT2or8tYkqYfjzPL9wNTRsJN40fffmk9s1Uz6PbbEOsNqkniCrsHjlG4I7MKBayEyj9KbhxGqp8tN23vC5K+lzg+CLhCVc4A727IY+8t1uCj9hv8OAqYPqiatWpH/7ANOsUaHXl4UGSHhnwqssBs1/1meUilvdkgIrhy7u2+1TW+z1jMN3+lQQ1KvLvexxDrDapJ4gq7WpqakyUIlysQ6w2qSeIKu5a8gxPgjph7EOsNqkniCrumRpycuiwkwcJ1QcdikvX8AIeS1LF1SedADwU6eU9IaCaZCAig5yMBccvSRKT+W+ZsfPoLN5c0IliYMwnHbAfXwhKi3O/+L9SyeKeLupHtA9S+XKwz97LvEOsNqkniCrvIh6xV3cNuuKS12MjOBUQSs4y2qNXPFKw==","extGuestTotal":"0","roomTotal":"4350","servicetaxTotal":"466","discount":"385.0","commission":"0","originalRoomTotal":"3965"}},{"ratetype":"Y","hotelPackage":"N","roomtype":"Super Deluxe Double Room","roombasis":",Complimentary Wi-Fi Internet, Breakfast, ","roomTypeCode":"0000017101","ratePlanCode":"0000120713","ratebands":{"validdays":"1111111","wsKey":"mPRyZ7i+l3d9YkBTbyd4CsQ6w2qSeIKubc0g8TGBVVSbBYEQK7zdOgbJJqjW5wOwiG065xYCyu+vVu5bgidY3mfECYFCkMSIn4KACQv3zPbHDVCqduGZ/cYclnMQGbwGDufqO8lYtnyH9KjpH
```

Here is the ajax request

```
$.ajax({
          url:'session.php',
          data:{userdata:JSON.stringify(data)},
          method:"POST",
          success:function(data){
              alert(data);
              console.log(data);
          },
          error:function(err){
             alert('error'+err);
            }
       });
```

In php

```
$arr=json_decode($_POST['userdata']);
foreach($arr as $v){
    print_r($v);
}
```

Getting this error

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach

Comment: try `json_decode($_POST['userdata'], true)`, by default `json_decode` returns an object

Comment: tried but the same output

Comment: then echo `var_dump($arr)` to check what you've got in your variable

Comment: i will get the following object,object length(43),string

Comment: change `JSON.stringify(data)` to `data` in your ajax

Comment: Getting null o var_dump

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the following:

```
foreach($arr->data as $mydata) {
  echo $mydata->ratetype . "\n";
}
```

Replace `ratetype` with the appropriate data you are looking for.

Comment: Trying to get property of non object

Answer (score 0):

You have error in your json syntax

Your json should be

```
 var data =  '[{"ratetype":"Y","hotelPackage":"N","roomtype":"Deluxe Double Room","roombasis":",Complimentary Wi-Fi Internet, Breakfast, ","roomTypeCode":"0000015468","ratePlanCode":"0000120709","ratebands":{"validdays":"1111111","wsKey":"fOnrQW3wP9U6eaST9cxEwNldIVM6N6LdxDrDapJ4gq4xUB8SLli5fMQ6w2qSeIKuoaZbT2or8tYkqYfjzPL9wNTRsJN40fffmk9s1Uz6PbbEOsNqkniCrsHjlG4I7MKBayEyj9KbhxGqp8tN23vC5K+lzg+CLhCVc4A727IY+8t1uCj9hv8OAqYPqiatWpH/7ANOsUaHXl4UGSHhnwqssBs1/1meUilvdkgIrhy7u2+1TW+z1jMN3+lQQ1KvLvexxDrDapJ4gq7WpqakyUIlysQ6w2qSeIKu5a8gxPgjph7EOsNqkniCrumRpycuiwkwcJ1QcdikvX8AIeS1LF1SedADwU6eU9IaCaZCAig5yMBccvSRKT+W+ZsfPoLN5c0IliYMwnHbAfXwhKi3O/+L9SyeKeLupHtA9S+XKwz97LvEOsNqkniCrvIh6xV3cNuuKS12MjOBUQSs4y2qNXPFKw==","extGuestTotal":"0","roomTotal":"4350","servicetaxTotal":"466","discount":"385.0","commission":"0","originalRoomTotal":"3965"}},{"ratetype":"Y","hotelPackage":"N","roomtype":"Super Deluxe Double Room","roombasis":",Complimentary Wi-Fi Internet, Breakfast, ","roomTypeCode":"0000017101","ratePlanCode":"0000120713","ratebands":{"validdays":"1111111","wsKey":"mPRyZ7i+l3d9YkBTbyd4CsQ6w2qSeIKubc0g8TGBVVSbBYEQK7zdOgbJJqjW5wOwiG065xYCyu+vVu5bgidY3mfECYFCkMSIn4KACQv3zPbHDVCqduGZ/cYclnMQGbwGDufqO8lYtnyH9KjpH"}}]';
```

In html

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.ajax',function(){ 
        var id = '[{"ratetype":"Y","hotelPackage":"N","roomtype":"Deluxe Double Room","roombasis":",Complimentary Wi-Fi Internet, Breakfast, ","roomTypeCode":"0000015468","ratePlanCode":"0000120709","ratebands":{"validdays":"1111111","wsKey":"fOnrQW3wP9U6eaST9cxEwNldIVM6N6LdxDrDapJ4gq4xUB8SLli5fMQ6w2qSeIKuoaZbT2or8tYkqYfjzPL9wNTRsJN40fffmk9s1Uz6PbbEOsNqkniCrsHjlG4I7MKBayEyj9KbhxGqp8tN23vC5K+lzg+CLhCVc4A727IY+8t1uCj9hv8OAqYPqiatWpH/7ANOsUaHXl4UGSHhnwqssBs1/1meUilvdkgIrhy7u2+1TW+z1jMN3+lQQ1KvLvexxDrDapJ4gq7WpqakyUIlysQ6w2qSeIKu5a8gxPgjph7EOsNqkniCrumRpycuiwkwcJ1QcdikvX8AIeS1LF1SedADwU6eU9IaCaZCAig5yMBccvSRKT+W+ZsfPoLN5c0IliYMwnHbAfXwhKi3O/+L9SyeKeLupHtA9S+XKwz97LvEOsNqkniCrvIh6xV3cNuuKS12MjOBUQSs4y2qNXPFKw==","extGuestTotal":"0","roomTotal":"4350","servicetaxTotal":"466","discount":"385.0","commission":"0","originalRoomTotal":"3965"}},{"ratetype":"Y","hotelPackage":"N","roomtype":"Super Deluxe Double Room","roombasis":",Complimentary Wi-Fi Internet, Breakfast, ","roomTypeCode":"0000017101","ratePlanCode":"0000120713","ratebands":{"validdays":"1111111","wsKey":"mPRyZ7i+l3d9YkBTbyd4CsQ6w2qSeIKubc0g8TGBVVSbBYEQK7zdOgbJJqjW5wOwiG065xYCyu+vVu5bgidY3mfECYFCkMSIn4KACQv3zPbHDVCqduGZ/cYclnMQGbwGDufqO8lYtnyH9KjpH"}}]';
        $.ajax({ 
        url             :   'server.php', 
        data            :   {"da":id}, 
        method          :   "POST", 
        success:function(data)
        {
            $(".result").html(data);
        }, 
        error:function(err)
        { 
            alert('error'+err); 
        } 
        }); 
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" class="ajax" name="details" value="details">
<div class="result">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In php use

```
<?php
$arr= json_decode($_POST['da']);
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($v);
    echo "</pre>";
}

?>
```

Comment: I am passing this as an ajax request please take look at my ajax request

Comment: Its autogenereated json

Comment: Then add manually... i dont know.. all i know is you have error in your json syntax... :)

Comment: actually my json is in correct format,its typo occurred when it placed in the question

Comment: Okk then change `JSON.stringify(data)` to `data` in your ajax... and check if you getting the json completely in your page...

Comment: Changed echo $_POST['userdata'] gives `object object` but json_decode($_POST['userdata']) giving null response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103696/discussion-between-praveen-kumar-and-blessan-kurien).